# changing a picker to table view OR having multiple table views on the same view

Tags: iphone, uitableview, ipad, uipickerview

My iPad app was rejected due to my use of a picker. The picker was used to control a table view. In my view, a picker was displaying a series of items and when one of those items was selected, it used that selection to populate a table with data. (hopefully that makes sense). Now I need to do this without the picker so I need to have the data that was in the picker be represented in a table view.

My question, is how do I have multiple tableViews in the same view?

is it as simple as having separate delegate methods for each tableview like this?

```
-(NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView1
{

    return [xxx count];

}

-(NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView2
{

    return [yyy count];

}
```

Comment: I don't think this might be cause. Did apple told anything in the reply back email? Usually apple specifies the reason for rejection.

Comment: Yes they said pickers could only be used in popover views, which was not what I was doing.

Comment: What a reason! It's never specified in the doc of UIPickerView.

Comment: I did find it in the iPad guidelines after the fact. It's even in bold, lol "Present a picker or date and time picker only within a popover."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The names of the delegate methods are fixed. So you can either

1. Use two different delegate instances, or
2. Identify the table within the method, e.g.

   ```
   -(NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
       if (tableView.tag == 114)
         return [xxx count];
       else
         return [yyy count];
   }
   ```

Comment: with me being a noob, can you expand on "Use two different delegate instances "?

Comment: @Brodie: For example, you create `@interface A` and `@interface B`, then assign `tableA.dataSource` to an instance of A, and `tableB.dataSource` to an instance of B.